# unsure of what application.js in webpacker-rails is requiring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpacker

I have a rails 6 application with

```
gem 'webpacker', '~> 4.0'
gem 'react-rails'
```

included in the gemfile,

I've run `rails webpacker:install:react`  `rails generate react:install` and `yarn install`

And I notice that there is an application.js file present in my javascript/packs folder:

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.

require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")


// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
// const images = require.context('../images', true)
// const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

Why does it need to require those specific items?
Why are some of the requires prefixed with `@rails` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your application, you may be able to remove some or all of those requires.

- the `@rails/ujs` package adds unobtrusive JavaScript features like ajaxifying a form with the `remote: true` option, and adding the CSRF token to Ajax requests.
- `turbolinks` “makes it faster to navigate the application. When you follow a link, Turbolinks automatically fetches the page, swaps in its body tag and merges its head tag, all without incurring the cost of a full page load.” If using, use with care and understand the tradeoffs https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/blob/master/README.md
- the `@rails/activestorage` package is only necessary if you’re using ActiveStorage on the backend to support file uploads
- the `channels` package is only necessary if you’re using the Rails websocket feature ActionCable

The `@rails/` prefix is just part of the given package’s name to indicate that it is owned by an org; this is typically just a way to avoid name conflicts with other packages that might have the same name.

Comment: Thank you! that was pretty clear. Subscribed to your newsletter as well! Thank you for kindly sharing your knowledge @rossta

Comment: Thanks, glad that helped.

Comment: Can you provide more info about what kind of AJAX request for `@rails/ujs`, please?